# Python at front end and C++ at backend

Tags: python, c++, plugins, pymol

I am supposed to develop GUI using python for an application coded in C++. It is to be used as a **PyMOL plugin**.
How do I decide among the different options like ctypes, Boost.Python, SWIG, wxPython or Pyrex(?)? 
I'm quite new to Python and have had very little experience with C/C++. 
Also, I have the Python code for GUI of a similar application. How can I identify the type of Python-C++ interface used in it?

I don't see any of the following in the Python code:

import wx

from ctypes import *

Comment: Read the documentation?  Take a look at the build process, and talk to the numpty who gave this job to you.  Surely if they gave you a similar application someone has some idea how it works?

Comment: If it's a PyMOL plugin, should it work the same?  I dunno, but the PyMOL wikipedia page says it uses Tk.

Comment: @cdarke: The one who coded the application has left the institute and left no documentation except the installation guide.

Comment: But how do I decide among the different options like ctypes, Boost.Python, SWIG, wxPython or Pyrex(?)?

Comment: Honestly, it is partly experience.  To be effective with all these you really have to know about C++ and Python.  `ctypes` is OK unless you are switching between Python and C++ regularly.  SWIG is pretty good, and I would add SIP to your list, but it is difficult to say which is the most appropriate without inspecting the code.  Best I can suggest is you pick one and see how it goes.  Which GUI do you intend to use?

Comment: Thank you so much @cdarke. I am not very smart with computer terminologies. I hope I am making sense. We have the executable written in C++, and it works from its command prompt. 
Now, it is to be used as a PyMOL plugin. So, the GUI is to be coded in Python.

Comment: *I am not very smart with computer terminologies* - don't do yourself down, no one knows it all - those who think they do know even less.  I've never use PyMOL, so I can't advise on that.  Is the C++ code is a full blown executable or a library file (DLL on Windows or .so file on Linux/UNIX/OS X)?

Comment: @cdarke: It is an executable. '.exe' file, since it is an application currently being used using command line.

Comment: In that case, NONE of those interfaces you mention are relevant!  Those you mentioned are all for calling single functions within a library, not for calling a full executable.  Therefore, you probably need the python `subprocess` module.  If you show a sample command-line session, with the kind of data you need to capture, I'll try to help.

Comment: @cdarke Thanks a lot..!

Comment: I believe the exe file is kind of an intellectual property here. I don't have it in my system.But from your comment I think what I need to do is rather create a command for input to the executable and use subprocess (Popen?). 

Inputs are 
1. Filenames with path
2. Directory path for storing result files
3. Few integer parameters

However, for the output,the executable writes into .txt and .mol2 files. But I need to list the output data on the GUI (Multilistbox) of the plugin. Reading the files seems to be a way. But isn't that too twisted?

Comment: Sounds good to me so far.  Does the .exe run to completion and then you look at the data to plot onto the GIU (straightforward), or, does the .exe run in the background while you look at the output files in real-time?  I ask because there can be buffering issues in the second case.

Comment: In addition, some programs have the option of writing output to the standard output stream (stdout) instead of files.  That option can be very useful if your program has it.

Comment: The program is for comparing a molecule to a database of molecules. One test run result folder had over 10kB size. Reading it resulted in "Python.exe" stopped working. However, I have restricted the results to first 100 molecules. 
They program does not write the results onto the console. (I hope that's what you meant.) I think it's because of the large size and format of the output- too many lines and too many tables.